# Matplotlib tick labels

Tags: matplotlib

Is there a way to render the tick labels just right inside the axes, i.e, something like the *direction* property there is on the ticks themself?

Right now I'm setting the x property to a positive value on the ticklabels to draw them inside of the axis, i.e.,

```
ax2.set_yticklabels(['0', '2500', '5000', '7500'], minor=False, x=0.05)
```

But this doesn't really work on resizable plots, as the 0.05 figure is absolute (and too big on big plots).

Any ideas?

Comment: Does `ax2.tick_params('y', direction='in')[http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params]` help?

Comment: No I don't get that to work. It seems like setting the direction to 'in' on tick_params will draw the *ticks* inside of the axis, but not the tick_labels.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `ax2` is constructed as `ax2 = ax.twinx()`, which is to say that it is on the right side of the axes.

You could do something like the following:

```
ax2.set_yticklabels(['0', '2500', '5000', '7500'], minor=False, horizontalalignment='right')
for tick in ax2.yaxis.get_major_ticks():                                        
        tick.set_pad(-8)
```

If you want the left side axis on the inside too, then you'd simply switch the horizontal alignment to `'left'` and change the pad from `-8` to `-25`.

The two numbers might not be exact and could depend on other matplotlib settings you might have (e.g. length of major ticks) so you may want to increase or decrease those values slightly.